# Best framework/language for cross-platform modern GUI designs

Tags: qt, user-interface, frameworks, programming-languages

Qt Widgets is my daily driver right now, but I feel like it is getting too basic for my needs and I am looking for something which is a bit more advanced.

What is a good language and framework for this task?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by word "advanced"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're familiar with Qt, [QtQuick](https://wiki.qt.io/Introduction_to_Qt_Quick) can be a logical next step. QtQuick offers far more graphical functionality and modern capabilities than Qt widgets by comparison.

The learning curve for QML can be a little steep at first, but the included examples when you install Qt do a pretty good job introducing the major concepts. Once I got the hang of it I've never wanted to bother with Qt widgets again.

Comment: I agree with you that `QML gives more graphical functionality and it is modern` **but** `it depends on what he wants to do`. he didn't say anything about his project and what he wants.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just providing an answer given the limited context they've provided... If someone's familiar with Qt Widgets and wants something "more advanced", a logical recommendation for what to look into is QtQuick.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll check it out. Sorry for the limited context, but I thought Qt Quick might be the next step.